# Persist performance gradually decreasing

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

Given: Method in a `@Stateless` EJB, JTA Mysql data source and a list of about 5000 entities which I'm trying to persist in a cycle :

```
List<MyObj> objList = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Q1", MyObj.class).getResultList();
for(MyObj obj : objList) {
  long start_time = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
  entityManager.persist(obj);
  long end_time = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
  logger.info("Object saved in " + (end_time - start_time) + "ms");
}
entityManager.close();
```

Log shows gradually decreasing performance from `15ms` up to `180ms` save time per entity. I believe Mysql sever settings are far beyond the needs of this task - it shows insignificant increase in CPU and I/O operations. Flushing `EntityManager` after each update has no effect.

What could be the reason for such performance decrease? Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like slowdown is caused by large number of entities in persistence context (i.e. in its session cache). `flush` doesn't help here because it doesn't remove entities from persistence context.

If you need to process a large number of entities using a single persistence context it's recommended to clear the context with `clear()` periodically.